# Warp in Phoshop: transform lines from curved to straight

Tags: adobe-photoshop, images

I have the following image:

[image: Original image]

Is there a way to easily "straighten" the lines, in order to obtain the following image?

[image: Straightened image]

I have done this with the "Liquify" command. As you can see, the result is far from being perfect, but maybe there is something easier and better, e.g. using something like warping or other similar options.

I am currently using Photoshop 2018.

Can someone suggest which is the best way to achieve the desired result in this situation?

Comment: Retype it......

Comment: @Scott Actually that image is part of an entire old book of hundred pages. So retyping is not an option, but thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: @VitoGentile there are a lot op apps out there scanning an image and identifying the words and converting it to a word document.

Comment: Well with hundreds of pages, retyping would be *more* of an option to me as opposed to warping every page.

Comment: I do have to wonder what the use case for that image would be after you've flattened it perfectly....given that the picture quality is pretty poor to begin with. Seems like a lot of work for an end result that is going to look not-so-good either way, right? Are you sure it's worth it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Photosp's Edit > Transform > Warp is quite simple. It is easy to do as a 2 phase job. Before warping transform your text image layer to Smart Object to avoid sharpness loss due multiple twists.

At first use warp in Arc mode. -10% bending compensates most of the curvature. Do not worry out of the border text. It's still there, because this is a smart object:

[image]

Phase 2 is custom warping. Now it's good to have quides. I placed one, too:

[image]

Not as straightforward as some other options, but surely usable and it is in Photoshop.

The easiest method I know is to use much cheaper program Serif Affinity Photo (free fully functional trial is available). It has very flexible Mesh Warp tool. The needed bending seems to be global on the page, so the text is selected as whole and with the warp tool only the corner handles are adjusted. Nothing prevents to click and add more mesh nodes if needed. Your case needed only 1x1 mesh.

[image]

**If you have access to Illustrator**, you naturally use it. Object > Envelope Distort > Make with Mesh, mesh size=1 x 1 does the same as 1 x 1 mesh in Affinity Photo.

[image]

And then lunatic's method:

In a freeware 3D CAD program a spline curve was drawn along the baseline of your text. The spline was flipped vertically to get the concave side up. Then it was pulled to surface and your text clip was placed onto it. When the result is watched from the right direction, the lines seem straight.

[image]

Unfortunately the perspective causes the near side lines to seem longer than the far side lines. But that's easily fixed by switching the perspective OFF:

[image]

Finally the photo was stretched vertically to compensate the foreshortening.

**A late addition.** I found an older case with no answers, because the questioner didn't want especially little. He wanted some automation. But he got something. It can help also you. Read this: [How to straighten round-edge document or book page automatically?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/122572/how-to-straighten-round-edge-document-or-book-page-automatically)

Answer (score 2):

Well, with a little bit of practice you can do this quite fast using the Puppet Warp (Edit > Puppet warp).

To help guide you, add some guidelines under your rows.

[Here is a step by step tutorial on how to use the Puppet Warp.](http://www.dummies.com/software/adobe/photoshop/how-to-use-puppet-warp-in-photoshop-cs6/)

I did this in 20 seconds or so, with more time invested you will get better results.

[image]

> PS: there are a lot of apps out there that use OCR (Optical character
>   recognition) to scan an image and convert it to a text document.

Here is one of them [(Android)](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.renard.ocr) , I am sure you can find some **Image to text** apps for windows too.

Comment: Acrobat has OCR along with deskew, but I doubt it would do much good with the provided example. I don't know if it's in Acrobat Reader, but if I had to guess, I'd say it probably isn't.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**
- Under the filter dropdown select "lens correction."
- On the left menu, select the tool at the top "Remove Distortion Tool (D)."
- Pull on the image to straighten the bend in the text.

I think you'll get the best results with the Remove Distortion Tool, but you can also try using "Straighten Tool (A)" which is the one directly below the Remove Distortion Tool in this menu. To use the Straighten Tool, draw a diagonal line. Photoshop will rotate/distort the image until the diagonal line becomes straight.

Let me know if it works!